# I keep getting a warning that says polynomial is badly conditioned when I use polyfit() to find the polynomial

Tags: matlab, function, error-handling, warnings, matlab-figure

[dataIImport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxEQX.png)
(... ....more, till x = 2000).
These are the data I import.
[Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiZeN.png)
This is the warning I got. I don't get it why. When I tested with 0 is not 12.5. Instead, it's always 14.1394. Other students can get 12.5. I don't know where the problem is but I think my process is correct. I am not sure.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

You can not fit with polyfit with multiple values for the same X (or at least it's problematic). You need a different fitting method for that such as "ordinary least squares".
The problem is that you have two values for X=0, both y=0 and y=12.5.

Remove your 0,0 point as I assume this not an actual data point and it should work. At least that's the most I can help you unless you post the data as text.

X in matlab is what you would plot on your horizontal axis (you're variable that you vary), or in your case Z.
Y in matlab is the value from a function for a given X which is plot on the vertical axis, like Y=a*x+b, or in your case r. (this last paragraph is a bit generalised)